# Python script to continuously check the quality of wlan connection and output to GPIO

Tags: python, wifi, gpio

I'm trying to use this iwlist scan parsing script to turn on a GPIO (with attached LED), indicating a wireless connection:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
import subprocess
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

interface = "wlan0"
ledPin = 18

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(ledPin, GPIO.OUT)

def get_quality(cell):
    quality = matching_line(cell,"Quality=").split()[0].split('/')

    # This now returns a number
    return int(round(float(quality[0]) / float(quality[1]) * 100))

def matching_line(lines, keyword):
    """Returns the first matching line in a list of lines. See match()"""
    for line in lines:
        matching=match(line,keyword)
        if matching!=None:
            return matching
    return None

def match(line,keyword):
    """If the first part of line (modulo blanks) matches keyword,
    returns the end of that line. Otherwise returns None"""
    line=line.lstrip()
    length=len(keyword)
    if line[:length] == keyword:
        return line[length:]
    else:
        return None


def main():
    cells=[[]]
    parsed_cells=[]

    proc = subprocess.Popen(["iwlist", interface, "scan"],stdout=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True)
    out, err = proc.communicate()

    for line in out.split("\n"):
        cell_line = match(line,"Cell ")
        if cell_line != None:
            cells.append([])
            line = cell_line[-27:]
        cells[-1].append(line.rstrip())

    cells=cells[1:]

    for cell in cells:
        # get_quality now returns an integer
        qual =  get_quality(cell)
        if qual > 65:
            GPIO.output(ledPin, GPIO.HIGH)
        else:
            GPIO.output(ledPin, GPIO.LOW)

main()
```

I know it's missing some things like clean escape and GPIO.cleanup() but the main problem I'm having, even after hours and hours a google and experimenting, is that I can get the LED to light once, but I want to run this script in the background, checking connection every 20-30 seconds. Am I going about this the entirely wrong way? Is there an easier method to retrieve the wifi signal quality and return an INT  that can be used to manipulate GPIO?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are not calling main().

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```